# A confusion in the following scenerio of property class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a property class like Person class below. Properties include person’s basic information, college information and company information. When JSON data comes from the sever, I am allocating this person class and filling his/her information.

Person’s college will come only if he/she is studying and company information comes when he/she is working.  But I think when I am allocating person class I am initializing all properties but I need either college information properties or company information properties to be initialize. I don’t want to allocate unnecessary memory.

I am confused, whether initializing property to nil will work or I have to separate classes for college information and company information.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
@interface Person : NSObject

// Basic information
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *gender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *dateOfBirth;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *emailAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *contactAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *permanantAddress;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isWorking) BOOL *working;


// College Information
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *collegeName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *collegeAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *universityName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *enrolmentNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *courseName;
...
...
...

// Company Information
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *companyName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *companyAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *designation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *experience;
...
...
...

@end
```

Comment: Whether or not setting the properties to `nil` will work is merely a question of your design (do our methods and classes accept `nil` properties or do they crash on `nil` a la Java?) - now, separating different types of classes is good WRT design and architecture (google "single responsibility rule").

Comment: Have you looked into [JSONModel?](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/README.md#magical-data-modelling-framework-for-json)